# PHP displaying 1 instead of 01. How do I change it?

Tags: php

I tried `str_pad($i+1,STR_PAD_LEFT)`

But i had no sucess...

```
<?php echo'<td><strong>'.($i+1).'</strong>x de <strong>R$ '.number_format($valorParcela,2,',','.'). ' sem juros</strong></td> --- Total: R$' .number_format($valorParcela*($i+1),2,',',' ') ?> </option>
```

Be kind to help!

Thanks!

Comment: Close vote? It's PHP so we don't read the question yea? We click the close button straight away... I don't get it how this question is unclear ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
str_pad($i+1, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT)
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP will automatically truncate preceding 0's for number-type variables.  You can use str_pad with "0" (like `str_pad($+1, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT)`, or you can explicitly write: `echo "0".$i;` to have the whole thing treated as a string.

Answer (score 0):

This are the `str_pad` arguments:

> str_pad(string,length,pad_string,pad_type)

Change your code to:

```
str_pad($i+1, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Additional notes:

```
string      Required. Specifies the string to pad
length      Required. Specifies the new string length. If this value is less than the original length of the string, nothing will be done
pad_string  Optional. Specifies the string to use for padding. Default is whitespace
pad_type    Optional. Specifies what side to pad the string.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use str_pad
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php

```
$value = 1;
$padded_value = str_pad($value, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
echo $padded_value;
```